# How to keep null from displaying in internet explorer?

Tags: php, javascript, html, null, echo

The following is a section of my php page where I am displaying a variable based on weather or not it has a value. This works fine in Firefox and Chrome  but in internet explorer "null" is being displayed when the variables have no value rather than just being blank like in FF or Chrome. Is there a way to fix this?

```
<tr>
 <td>Track</td>
 <td><?php echo $trackResult. '&acute;<br/>';
    if($trackResultOne != NULL){ echo $trackResultOne."&acute;<br/>";}
    if($trackResultTwo != NULL){ echo $trackResultTwo."&acute;";}
    ?></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: PHP is processed server-sided and send the output to the browser. Can't understand, how it should make a difference between various web browsers. in general: Look for functions like `isset()` or `empty()`: http://php.net/manual/de/function.isset.php

Comment: @StefanBrendle, not completely. Don't forget that `'' == NULL`, which is equivalent to `empty('')`

Comment: are you sure those variables actually contain a PHP `null` value e.g. `isnull($trackResultOne)` is true, v.s. containing a **STRING** that happens to spell out `n`, `u`, `l`, `l`? You can check which case it is via `var_dump($trackResultOne)`.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunatelly, you will need to use the ELSE part of the IF to retrieve a blank (''), IE converts automatically the real null into the string 'null'.

Regards,

Pablo